# rabbitmq channel shutdown with PRECONDITION_FAILED - fast reply consumer does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-integration, amqp, spring-amqp

We are getting the below error when we are posting a message to rabbitmq from a spring boot service. Also this is intermittent and we are not able to reproduce this.

> [AMQP Connection 123.11.xxx.xx:5672] ERROR [] org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - fast reply consumer does not exist, class-id=60, method-id=40)

Does anyone faced similar issue with rabbitmq . 
Please help us with your inputs.

Comment: Precondition failed with channel shutdown usually indicates that something was attempting to re-declare a queue or exchange with different parameters than one that already exists.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else that ended up here due to this error, in my case the issue was resolved when I ensured both of the following:

- the publisher ("client") used the **same channel** for both publishing (to whatever normal queue you publish to) and for consuming from the RabbitMQ `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` queue
- the consumer ("server") used the **same channel** for both consuming (from whatever normal queue you published to above) and for publishing to the specified RabbitMQ `reply-to` queue

Unfortunately, I don't see this [documented](https://www.rabbitmq.com/direct-reply-to.html) anywhere.

Comment: So we need 2 channel for Client, first publish the request, then consume the queue.
and we need 2 channel for Server, first consume the request and then publish the response?

Comment: @ArminShoeibi I'm pretty sure the client needs to consume (subscribe to) the reply-to queue *before* publishing

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with direct reply mode and what I had to do was to:

1. Ensure that the consumer for the replies (not the requests) was running BEFORE publishing the request message.
2. Also, as the docs say:

> The RPC client must consume in the **automatic acknowledgement mode**. This is because there is no queue for the reply message to
> be returned to if the client disconnects or rejects the reply
> message.

3. I also used the same model/channel for the publisher and consumer, as user `joniba` said, but I am not sure if that has helped indeed.

Comment: Hello, I need a sample for Direct Reply-To with C#, could you please help me and share a sample on Github or Gitlab?

Comment: @ArminShoeibi Take a look here in case it helps: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html

Answer (score 0):

It most likely means the requestor has timed out and canceled the consumer on the direct replyTo queue. Or, the requesting application has been stopped.

If the requestor is also a Spring AMQP application, the default `replyTimeout` is 5000ms (5 seconds). If the server side takes longer than that, the requestor will timeout and you'll get this error on the server.

You can increase the `replyTimeout` property on the requesting `RabbitTemplate`.

**EDIT**

Spring AMQP 2.0.x (requires Spring Framework 5.x) uses longer-lived direct replyTo consumers so you shouldn't get these messages (but the client will still time out and you'll get a warning log on the client side and a log when the late delivery arrives).

Comment: Thanks Gary for the quick reply. actually i am trying to reproduce this in dev env could you please suggest me any way how can i re produce this from dev.

Comment: Either change the `replyTimeout` to a small value (e.g. 1ms) or put a fake delay on the server side. Also see my edit.

Comment: also I have 2 queues one is rpc one and the other is a normal queue just publishes the message to queue and won't expect any response. we observed this issue with the normal queue not the rpc one.could you please suggest me how can i reproduce this in local.

Comment: That makes no sense; if you are not using RPC then there won't be any attempt to send a reply so you can't get that error.

Comment: Will it be the case when both the rpc call and normal publish to queue using  the same channel from Rabbit Connection Factory.                                                               

http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#channel-threads

Comment: No; the channel is not returned to the cache for reuse until the request/reply operation is complete. What version of RabbitMQ are you using? I just ran a test and I don't get that exception, even if I reply too late; the broker just throws away the reply (like it does for any unroutable message).