# rabbitmq publish failed with PRECONDITION_FAILED - fast reply consumer does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp

We are getting the below error when we are posting a message to rabbitmq from a spring boot service.

> [AMQP Connection 123.11.xxx.xx:5672] ERROR [] org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - fast reply consumer does not exist, class-id=60, method-id=40)

Does anyone faced a similar issue with `rabbitmq`?

Please help us with your inputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rabbitmq channel shutdown with PRECONDITION\_FAILED - fast reply consumer does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821935/rabbitmq-channel-shutdown-with-precondition-failed-fast-reply-consumer-does-no)

Comment: Duplicate (same poster): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821935/rabbitmq-channel-shutdown-with-precondition-failed-fast-reply-consumer-does-no/48828511#48828511