# RabbitMQ error fast reply consumer does not exist when not using replyTo

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

I'm running into a bug where RabbitMQ is *sometimes* complaining about "PRECONDITION_FAILED - fast reply consumer does not exist" although as you can see below the message I send does not have a fast reply, the reply-to is `null`. About 50% of the time the message will get sent to the exchange/queue as I'm expecting and the other 50% of the time I am getting this error which destroys the message. I am running this code in spring boot 1.3.6 with spring amqp 1.6.0. RabbitMQ server is 3.5.5 with Erlan 18.1. I am unable to update the versions as this is production code.

My code is very simple. I declare a response exchange/queue for further communication.

```
amqpAdmin.declareExchange(exchange);
amqpAdmin.declareQueue(queue);
amqpAdmin.declareBinding(binding);
```

I send my amqp message to the exchange/routing key of a topic exchange, but it never makes it there due to the following error:

```
Publish Message Success: [MyObject], MessageProperties [headers={__TypeId__=com.do.comp.amqp}, timestamp=null, messageId=null, userId=null, appId=null, clusterId=null, type=null, correlationId=null, replyTo=null, contentType=application/json, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=97, deliveryMode=PERSISTENT, expiration=null, priority=0, redelivered=null, receivedExchange=null, receivedRoutingKey=null, deliveryTag=0, messageCount=null]]
```

---

```
AMQP Connection 10.12.36.75:5672 [ERROR] org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.log(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1198) - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - fast reply consumer does not exist, class-id=60, method-id=40)<br>
http-nio-8122-exec-7 [DEBUG] org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:476) - Creating cached Rabbit Channel from AMQChannel(amqp://admin@10.12.36.75:5672/,3)<br>
http-nio-8122-exec-7 [DEBUG] org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1392) - Executing callback on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://admin@10.12.36.75:5672/,3), conn: Proxy@782534f9 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@74658797 [delegate=amqp://admin@10.12.36.75:5672/, localPort= 60282]
```

Then I listen on the queue I created for a response that will never come:

```
rabbitTemplate.receive(queue);
```

The error above has to do with direct reply-to queues and I'm not using that, my reply-to messageHeader is null. Another odd thing is we are running this exact jar on three different servers for testing and development and only one of them seems to be having an issue, but they are all the same version of everything. RabbitMQ v.3.5.5 Erland 18.1

Why is RabbitMQ throwing a fast reply error when reply-to is null?

Comment: We need some code to reproduce. On the `RabbitTemplate` level the `amq.rabbitmq.reply-to` is use only when you perform `sendAndReceive()`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.11.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#direct-reply-to. Here is some discussion with RabbitMQ team as well: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/2hWtpypT2sk. Might be the fact that you need a fresh publishing channel. I mean do not reuse the same `ConnectionFactory` for receiving and sending.

Comment: Here is also some info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823323/rabbitmq-publish-failed-with-precondition-failed-fast-reply-consumer-does-not